# Microsoft Report Viewer hiding null rows in a table

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

We use grouping to display master-detail report.  If there are only nulls in a corresponding part of a report data source flat table, how can I not show empty records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide records in your report that have NULL values in one of the columns.

Is it an option to update your query to exclude these rows?

If this isn't an option, you can add a filter to the Dataset in the dataset property pages... you could use this filter to remove rows from the dataset that don't meet the criteria that you are looking for.